# Ubuntu 16.04 using a serial terminal with a FTDI chip usb virtual comport

Tags: drivers, usb

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS just freshly installed.

What kind of serial terminal will work best with a virtual-COM-Port cable that uses an FTDI-Chip?

What do I have to do for additional installations like virtual comport-driver, connecting hardware to "linux-files" like ".../usb0" etc?

I'm new to Linux so I need detailed guidance. A link to a tutorial "using USB-2-serial-adapters for dummies" would also help.

Answer (score 8):

The FTDI chip should be supported out-of-the box. Just connect the device and it will be available. The commands `lsusb` and `dmesg | tail` (directly after plugging in the device) are your friends here.

Serial COM Ports are addressed as `/dev/tty*` (hardware serial COM ports) while USB serials (like the FTDI chip) appear as `/dev/ttyUSB*` when they are connected.

Personally I like `moserial` which is available in the repository. Install it like so:

```
sudo apt install moserial
```

There you can configure your connection and read/write to the device.

Comment: I am using a Xchipi-X it doesn't work out of the box, and it's an FTDI chip.

Comment: Update: after 10 minutes of messing around with the chipi-X I unplugged it and replugged it, and it just worked. For the first 10 minutes there was no /dev/ttyUSB0. I don't know why. I didn't change anything to make it appear.

Comment: Can confirm that `moserial` detects and connects to an FTDI (FT232) USB cable no problem (Ubuntu 20.04). Appears as `/dev/ttyUSB0` when plugged in. `lsusb` shows it as `Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC`. Imma use it for connecting my Atari 400 to internet (SIO2PC)!